# SQL Query How to ensure that ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY... always has a ROW_NUMBER = '1' in result set

Tags: sql

I've created a view that returns a row number for each record. My requirements are that the results must always have a line 1, incremented by 1. This works fine as long as all line items are selected from a given record. However, when only some of the line items from a record are selected, the set of row numbers for the selected line items may or may not have a row number = 1. Below is an example of my code:

```
SELECT a.PATID, 
       a.PATID + '_' + a.BATCHID + '_' + a.UNIQUEID AS RECORD_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION_BY b.BATCHID, b.UNIQUIEID, b.LINE_ID) AS LN_NBR,
       a.ADMIT_DT, 
       b.REV, 
       b.SERVICE_DATE AS DOS
FROM HDR_TBL a 
LEFT JOIN LINE_ITEM_TBL b
WHERE b.PD_STATUS = 'P'
```

Here is an example of the results:

```
PATID |RECORD_ID |LN_NBR|ADMIT_DT |REV |DOS     |
-----|-----------|------|--------|----|--------|
21548|017_U50_011|1     |20170721|0124|20170721|
21548|017_U50_011|2     |20170722|0214|20170722|
21548|017-U50_011|3     |20170723|0124|20170723|
51245|017_U27_003|3     |20170701|0124|20170701|
51245|017_U27_003|4     |20170702|0124|20170702|
```

As you can see the last 2 records have LN_NBR = 3 and 4; I need to generate the last 2 record with LN_NBR = 1 and 2 instead.

Anyone have an idea how I can force this to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: I can think of no database where your query will run.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` Requires `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause...

Comment: Also the `LEFT JOIN` need `ON` condition

Comment: My bad, I left out the ORDER_BY b.LINE_ID and the left join ON = a.PATID AND a.BATCHID AND a.UNIQUEID

Answer (score 0):

Your `PARTITION BY` need to match your `RECORD_ID`

In this case should be

```
  OVER (PARTITION BY a.PATID, a.BATCHID, a.UNIQUEID ORDER BY <something>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the fields you should have in an `ORDER BY` condition in the `PARTITION BY` condition.  It should be:

```
SELECT a.PATID, 
       a.PATID + '_' + a.BATCHID + '_' + a.UNIQUEID AS RECORD_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION_BY a.RECORD_ID ORDER BY b.BATCHID, b.UNIQUIEID, b.LINE_ID) AS LN_NBR,
       a.ADMIT_DT, 
       b.REV, 
       b.SERVICE_DATE AS DOS
FROM HDR_TBL a 
LEFT JOIN LINE_ITEM_TBL b
WHERE b.PD_STATUS = 'P'
```